# IOS Xcode VSee framework wont compile

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

Hello I have the Vsee Framework for video chatting, I  opened the sample Project they have in there and it runs and everything its ok, and by that I meant, that it compiles.

Now I am trying to integrate it into a New project to test it and see how am I gonna integrate it in another (already done) project. I follow all the steps on the tutorial they have in a pdf, but in the end it fails to build with this error message:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_appId", referenced from:
      l001 in VSeeKit(vseeUIApplication.o)
  "_appName", referenced from:
      l001 in VSeeKit(vseeUIApplication.o)
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_IVAR_$_DDTTYLogger._appName)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Thanks in advance for replying.

Comment: forgot to mention that I  DID add the i386 Arch and the x86_64 arch , which also fails.

Comment: Can you please share sample project link?

Comment: Did you ever get to fix that issue?

Comment: Please share your sample project

Comment: Have you fixed the issue , if yes can you please share us the solution or sample code to download